# Calculate and divide by total with AWK

Tags: awk, arithmetic

Given the following `data` file...

```
foo     10
bar     20
oof     50
rab     20
```

... how would I print column two as a percent of the total of column two? In other words, I want...

```
foo     10    10%
bar     20    20%
oof     50    50%
rab     20    20%
```

... with less obvious numbers of course. I can create a running total easily enough, but I'm not sure how I can **calculate the total before printing the lines**. I am doing this in an awk file `totals.awk`...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{
        runningtotal=0
}
{
        runningtotal=runningtotal+$2
        print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" runningtotal "\t" $2/runningtotal
}
```

So, running `./totals.awk data` yields...

```
foo     10      10      1
bar     20      30      0.666667
oof     50      80      0.625
rab     20      100     0.2
```

Is there a way to loop twice, once to calculate the total, and once to print the lines? Is this possible in AWK, or must I use other utilities?

Comment: [How to Add Column with Percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8303367)

Comment: BTW you need not run it as `cat data | ./totals.awk`. Consider that `awk` WANTS a file, so just do a `./totals.awk data` (or if you insist, `totals.awk < data`, in this case it should not matter) instead. Anyways, the gist is: in any case, __omit__ that superfluous `cat`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To create the table with a single call to `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{s+=$2;next;} {printf "%s\t%s\t%s%%\n",$1,$2,100*$2/s}' data data
foo     10      10%
bar     20      20%
oof     50      50%
rab     20      20%
```

#### How it works

The file `data` is provided as an argument to `awk` twice.  Consequently, it will be read twice, the first time to get the total, which is stored in the variable `s`, and the second to print the output.  Looking at the commands in more detail:

- `FNR==NR{s+=$2;next;}`

  NR is the total number of records (lines) that `awk` has read and FNR is the number of records read so far from the current file.  Consequently, when `FNR==NR`, we are reading the first file.  When this happens, the variable `s` is incremented by the value in the second column.  Then, `next` tells `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and start over with the next record.

  Note that it is not necessary to initialize `s` to zero.  In `awk`, all numeric variables are, by default, initialized to zero.
- `printf "%s\t%s\t%s%%\n",$1,$2,100*$2/s`

  If we reach this command, then we are processing the second file.  This means that `s` now holds the total of column 2.  So, we print column 1, column 2, and the percentage, `100*$2/s`.

#### Output format options

With `printf`, detailed control of the output format is possible.  The command above uses the `%s` format specifier which works for strings, integers, and floats.  Three other option that might be useful here are:

- `%d` formats numbers as integers.  If the number is actually floating point, it will be truncated to an integer
- `%f` formats numbers as floating point.  It is also possible to specify widths and decimals places as, for example, `%5.2f`.
- `%e` provides exponential notation.  This would be useful if some numbers were exceptionally large or small.

#### Make a shell function

If you are going to use this more than once, it is an inconvenience to type a long command.  Instead create either a function or a script to hole the command.

To create a function called `totals`, run the command:

```
$ totals() { awk 'FNR==NR{s+=$2;next;} {printf "%s\t%s\t%s%%\n",$1,$2,100*$2/s}' "$1" "$1"; }
```

With this function defined, the percentages for a data file called `data` can be found by running:

```
$ totals data
```

To make the definition of `totals` permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### Make a shell script

If you prefer a script, create a file called `totals.sh` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
awk 'FNR==NR{s+=$2;next;} {printf "%s\t%s\t%s%%\n",$1,$2,100*$2/s}' "$1" "$1"
```

To get the percentages for a data file called `data`, run:

```
sh totals.sh data
```

Comment: Isn't good to use `%d` for second and third columns instead of `%s` for them?!

Comment: @KasiyA Based on your suggestion, I added a section on `printf` formats.  `%s` will show integer or floating point as the number requires.  `%d` would, of course, truncate floating point numbers to integer, potentially losing accuracy.  Whether that format is better than more precise output is, I think, a matter for the OP to decide.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting stuff. __But do not even *think* of using this in `C`__! As `awk`'s `printf` syntax is pretty alike to the `C` syntax, this looks sooo darn tempting. But `C`, in contrary, will show itself obdurate here once more (just *had* to test it! :)) `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`. Trying to run that program even resulted in a __segfault__...!---So what this post is supposed to say is: don't assume that what you can do in `awk` would be possible in `C` as well. `awk` is WAY more liberal in that respect.

Comment: @John1024 you can also use the form `file{,}` for two files or add more commas for more, it saves space if filenames are large.

Comment: I don't need a one-liner - in fact I am hoping for a .awk file which I can call like `./totals.awk data`. Is there a way to make this work without needing to input the file twice like `./totals data data`? I appreciate the explanations btw.

Comment: @Nate I have added sections for making the code into (a) shell function or (b) a shell script.  Both work as well.  Both eliminate the need for write the file name twice.  Use whichever approach you are more comfortable with.

Answer (score 4):

The "simple" way of doing this would be to call `awk` twice: once to get the total, another time to calculate the ratios.

```
$ total=$(awk 'BEGIN{ total=0 } { total=total+$2 } END{ printf total }' data)
$ awk -v total=$total '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" 100*$2/total "%" }' data
```

Now I'm sure someone will come up with a one-liner somehow...

Comment: Just a +1 for *not* using `cat`. It always hurts my eyes to see `cat` "misused" like that. Poor `cat`! (meow) ;)

Comment: Another alternative would be to use input redirection: this would even save `awk` the trouble of opening the file.

Comment: Yes, but chances are the latter will not be entirely POSIX-compliant then. (From the top of my head though, would have to try it out to be sure, perhaps I'm again confusing it with *command substitution* ;))

Answer (score 4):

Awk way with one file open(for completeness)

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0;x+=(b[NR]=$2)}END{while(++i<=NR)print a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x"%"}' file

foo     10      10%
bar     20      20%
oof     50      50%
rab     20      20%
```

This will use more memory than the others but should be faster

This reads the line into array `a` and field two into array `b`.
Then increments `x` by the value in field 2.

At the end it iterates from 1 to the number of records and outputs the correct line and calculates the percentage.

Comment: Is there a way to parse the output stored in the associative array `a` inside of `END`? Say I only wanted to print the first column and the percentage.

Comment: @Nate There is but i don't think it would be necessary, you could just save the first column instead of the line, `a[NR]=$1` instead of `a[NR]=$0`