# How to calculate percent of every column?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to transform some data to a percent of the total of each column, very similar to this thread except that I need to do this for every column:
[Calculate and divide by total with AWK](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174371/calculate-and-divide-by-total-with-awk/174405#174405?newreg=6bf3e6edec0f475397c5840d5029cae5)

Data would like something like this (but more columns and rows):

```
ID     Sample1     Sample2      Sample3
One      10          0            5
Two      3           6            8
Three    3           4            7
```

And the desired output would look like this:

```
ID     Sample1     Sample2     Sample3
One     62.50        0.0        25.0
Two     18.75       60.0        40.0
Three   18.75       40.0        35.0
```

The following works for a single column, but I want to do this for
every column, except the first one.

```
gawk -F"\t" '{a[NR]=$1;x+=(b[NR]=$2)}END{while(++i<=NR)print a[i]"\t"100*b[i]/x}' file.txt
```

Thanks a lot for any help you might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% the same output as you asked, but hopefully close enough:

```
function percent(value, total) {
    return sprintf("%.2f", 100 * value / total);
}
{
    label[NR] = $1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sum[i] += col[i][NR] = $i
    }
}
END {
    title = label[1]
    for (i = 2; i <= length(col) + 1; ++i) {
        title = title "\t" col[i][1];
    }
    print title
    for (j = 2; j <= NR; ++j) {
        line = label[j]
        for (i = 2; i <= length(col) + 1; ++i) {
            line = line "\t" percent(col[i][j], sum[i]);
        }
        print line
    }
}
```

Produces output:

> ```
> ID    Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
> One   62.50   0.00    25.00
> Two   18.75   60.00   40.00
> Three 18.75   40.00   35.00
> ```

Run it with `gawk -f script.awk file.txt`

Of course, you *could* flatten the script to a single line,
but I think it's better to keep it in a script file like this so it's easier to read and maintain.

A simpler and better version that works with BSD AWK too, not only GNU AWK:

```
function percent(value, total) {
    return sprintf("%.2f", 100 * value / total)
}
BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }
NR == 1 { gsub(/ +/, OFS); print; next }
{
    label[NR] = $1
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
        sum[i] += col[i, NR] = $i
    }
}
END {
    for (j = 2; j <= NR; ++j) {
        $1 = label[j]
        for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) {
            $i = percent(col[i, j], sum[i])
        }
        print
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks janos, this indeed does work for this sample data.  But I actually have more columns and rows, is it possible that this could be more general, i.e. do the exact same function independent of the number of columns?  As I will need to run this on files that have different numbers of columns, sometimes 20, sometimes 200, etc.  Again, thanks for your help.